# How to convince someone there is a conspiracy?

Tags: conspiracies

How to convince someone there is a conspiracy? I might point out that they are an important person, that they are involved in conspiracy like behaviour, that conspiracies are not unheard of, that I am not lying when I think there is one, that events similar to the alledged conspiracy are currently happening (and they acknowledge this) etc. etc.. I don't mean I have evidence that the moon landings are fake, but how would you convince someone to talk it over before deciding they don't need to test themselves for [syphilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuskegee_Syphilis_Study)?

Comment: The IEP [has a somewhat disconcerting entry about conspiracy theories](https://iep.utm.edu/conspiracy-theories/), for whatever it's worth.

Comment: haha mad @KristianBerry i might email them my theory :D "what did IEP know?"

Comment: Providing evidence supporting the hypotheses about the conspiracy.

Comment: without speaking to them (what would you class as evidence?) and their friends (who can you rely on?), it's neigh impossible to do anything except raise suspicions (barring someone in the conspiracy having a crisis of confidence/etc.). hmm @MauroALLEGRANZA outside hacks anyway

Comment: Why focus so much on "how to convince someone of X" instead of "how can I know I'm justified in believing X?" Do you already assume you're justified?

Comment: oh no it's not that kind of conspiracy @TKoL given X thinks Y, i know that Y is false, supposing X does think Y, but they X won't tell me... it's just schizophrenia, all of it!

Comment: Evidence and arguments are the only way. If they are enough in a trial to convince the court/jury to sentence a human being (in some cases up to death), they must be enough "to kill an hypotheses".

Comment: I think the harder problem is convincing people that there is **not** a conspiracy. Maybe we could just flip it around and tell people it is a conspiracy against a conspiracy? Two for one!

Comment: i agree with that @MauroALLEGRANZA but to an extent this imaginary conspiracy (bear in mind i'm d/g schizophrenic, so i'm not the usual conspiracy theorist) can be proven with a simple dna test, which no court would deny me (if it went to court)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hallmark of conspiracy theory (in the pejorative sense) is that they focus narrowly on *people* — and in particular on corrupt, malignant motivation — to the exclusion of facts and events. A conspiracy theory is (in essence) the construction of a dystopian narrative in which a group of people coordinate for some negative or subversive goal. A conspiracy is unmasked when we start to see evidence that people in a group are working towards a goal. A conspiracy theory (by contrast) tends to rework its narrative to account for absent or contradictory evidence.

So, if you want to convince someone a conspiracy is true, you need to do one of two things:

- show evidence that two or more people are coordinating to produce a given (factual) outcome that none of them openly admit to
- demonstrate that a given (factual) outcome could not reasonably occur without the coordination of two or more people

These are, in fact, the standard procedures in RICO cases.

Comment: "that none of them openly admit to" - plenty of conspiracies have come to light exactly *because* some people openly admit to it. This is the exact reason recent conspiracy theories involving practically every government in the world or all scientists (or both) are so implausible, because you need so many people to work together to hide something, respectively including parties openly hostile towards one another and anyone who goes to any university for a few years, and not a single person among any of them tells others about it (including hiding it from family members).

Comment: "*Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events; small minds discuss people.*" - Eleanor Roosevelt

Comment: @ScottRowe: I thought that was Socrates…

Comment: @TedWrigley well, either way, it's still a good one. I try to attribute, but in some cases of these famous memes, it is actually murky. But I attribute so that people can investigate further, like saying that a quote came from a particularly good book. I'm reading "The Genetic Lottery" now, it's up there with "Caste" and "The Demon Haunted World". Didn't there used to be some list of " great books" or something? No good thing ever came out of Chicago :-)

Answer (score 4):

Let's define a conspiracy as a concealed coordinated effort by multiple, apparently unconnected parties, to create a convincing illusion of something counter to the actual state of affairs. Some conspiracies uncontroversially exist, or have existed, such as when companies that are putatively rivals coordinate to fix prices. However, it's also uncontroversial that many people believe in conspiracies that are imaginary.

Given that, what makes it reasonable for someone to believe or disbelieve in a conspiracy? There's three considerations that feed into whether or not a conspiracy is believable.

1. Do all the involved parties have enough self-interest to justify the effort (of coordinating and concealing)? And is the secrecy necessary to those interests? A lot of times the powers-that-be just operate in the open, it's easier and more efficient.
2. Are the logistics of the conspiracy realistically manageable? The larger it gets, the harder it is to keep everyone in line, and make sure the stories all line up.
3. (To borrow from the accepted answer:) Are there plausible alternate explanations other than conspiracy? Using the principle of the simpler explanation, we wouldn't turn to "conspiracy" as the answer if simpler answers serve the purpose. For instance, if a group of people shares a vested interest, it doesn't take a conspiracy to explain all of them acting to protect that interest. It might seem coordinated, but it doesn't have to be. It might have the impact of conspiracy, but the source is just individual venality (which is arguably harder to combat).

It's always possible to hypothesize a conspiracy for any given situation--since a successful conspiracy is convincing by definition. But if you want to convince your friend, you'll have to be able to cover the above questions.

Comment: depends on who you blame. american intelligence is worth 100 billion plus a year. globally it'll probably be *this* side of a trillion, but that's annually. how powerful is elon musk vs how powerful is the united states government (who can break some [laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licence_to_kill_(concept)) without any fear whatsoever)? either way, you can be sure they are watching you, and there are e.g. putin bots on the sites you use. specifically, i am talking about phone hacks, which are not so "out there", and personally it'd be more about motive and opportunity than hermetic seals

Comment: Agencies that require secrecy (proprietary information, national security) as part of their business are the easiest targets. The more open the agency the less likely it will be a target of conspiracy theories.

Comment: @IdiosyncraticSoul NASA publishes most of his fidings, pictures, plans, technologies, budgeting... probably one of the most open organizations in the world. Yet it's the object of the most ludicrous conspiracy theories out there (moon landing hoax, flat earth, aliens, etc)

Comment: @armand I agree and completely forgot about  Discovery Channels "NASAs Unexplained Files" and all other similar programming.

Comment: I think that most everything people believe in is imaginary. If it wasn't, they would know instead of believing.

Answer (score 0):

That probably depends on the specifics. Like what is the conspiracy, who are the conspirators, what are your options to deal with that, who could be your allies against that, what do you know, how trustworthy are your sources and evidence etc. And also what is your role in that. Like are you an average dude who has been made aware of that by "RE:RE:RE:WAHT THE GUBBERMENT DOESN'T WANT YOU TO KNOW!!!11eleven" then you're in a different position than if you are a journalist who has means to investigate and ultimately publish their findings or if you are close to the action maybe even a co-conspirator and thus could act as a whistleblower.

Also there's a difference between a conspiracy of criminals where you can simply talk to the police/DA/lawyers/journalists or whether it's a conspiracy by high ranking officials where lots of those roads might be blocked and where you likely need to address a global audience or a major player to assert diplomatic pressure.

Also be aware that if you make ridiculous claims, you will look like a weirdo, so just because the cop or journalist tells you to GTFO, because of your flimsy evidence for an unbelievable claim, that does not mean that they are necessarily "in on it", it could also mean that you're not the first to make ridiculous grandstanding claims without evidence to boost their ego and that 99 times out of 100 it's a waste of time and that in their career they are on a solid 84 streak already. So it's pretty easy to get unreasonably paranoid.

Though regardless of your position in it and the scale and scope of the conspiracy it probably helps tremendously if people don't just have to take your word for it or at least if your word stands for something.

And the other thing worth thinking about is whether it's actually a good idea to want to catch them red handed (and if you even have the means to do that) and thus should engage yourself in a conspiracy to unravel a conspiracy or whether you just care about them not succeeding with it. Because rather than pointing out that a group of people is secretly trying to exploit a loophole, you can just raise awareness of that loophole in the first place. So that it is either closed in time or the awareness of the dirty business leads to an erosion of trust and goodwill that taints whatever they tried to accomplish with it.

The thing is actual conspiracies work really well in domains of secrecy and hierarchy both kinda antithetical to a republic (res publica = matter of the public) and a democracy (rule of the people) so more often than not you either already have means to mitigate conspiracies by demanding transparency and participation of your own or you should rather demand those over complaining that a system that is likely to be abused is in fact getting abused.

In case of the [Tuskegee Syphilis Study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuskegee_Syphilis_Study), that you cite as example I'm not really sure that still counts as "conspiracy". As you'd nowadays expect something clandestine, but apparently that was rather blatant. That was apparently pitched to the CDC and PHS, got funding, went through several administrations and supervisors was already exposed more or less by mandatory syphilis testing upon enlistment, the results were **publicized** and people complained about ethics violations at least as early as 1955. In 1965 someone criticized it by READING THE ARTICLE.

> In 1965, Schatz read an article about the study in a medical journal and wrote a letter directly to the study's authors confronting them with a declaration of brazen unethical practice.

> In 1966, Peter Buxtun, a PHS venereal-disease investigator in San Francisco, sent a letter to the national director of the Division of Venereal Diseases expressing his concerns about the ethics and morality of the extended U.S. Public Health Service Syphilis Study at Tuskegee.[36] The CDC, which by then controlled the study, reaffirmed the need to continue the study until completion; i.e. until all subjects had died and been autopsied. To bolster its position, the CDC received unequivocal support for the continuation of the study, both from local chapters of the National Medical Association (representing African-American physicians) and the American Medical Association (AMA).

So there was apparently no realization of wrong doing by officials and apart from lying to the patients of the study, not even an attempt at secrecy. So people didn't need to be convinced so much as the evidence were already in public the public was just not aware of it. Yeah in those cases you'd need broadcasting to spread message as you already have evidence and trustworthy sources, but more importantly you need a receptive audience, if they had broken the news in the 1930's or even 1950s in the worst case you'd have public knowledge about the case, but no public outrage. If that weren't the case one probably would need to address the international community and committees tasked with human rights violations.

As a true "goes all the way to the top"-conspiracy, is not something that you could easily deal with inside of such a country to begin with, if you are without either popular support or support by the authorities (including a free press to gather popular support).